# Remove number from FaceTime

Tags: facetime, ios

On a recent visit to US I bought a pre-paid SIM for use during my visit.

On my iPad this number (which is now expired) is still shown in a number of places - in particular "You can be reached by FaceTime at".

How can I remove this number?

Comment: Did you try this: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201349#remove ?

Comment: @NimeshNeema I had seen something similar in answer to an old question, but was hoping there was an easier more modern way. My AppleID is used for Family Sharing on 6 Macs and more iDevices than I care to think about. Last time I was forced to change it took a week to get everything updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can disassociate/remove the number from FaceTime/Messages by following the steps outlined in the Apple support document, [Add or remove your phone number in Messages or FaceTime](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201349#remove):

> #### Remove your phone number
>
> If you don't want calls or messages for your iPhone on your iPad, iPod touch, or Mac, you can remove your phone number. There are two ways to do this:
>
> - On your iPhone, go to Settings > Messages > Send & Receive. Select your Apple ID and tap Sign Out. Then go to Settings > FaceTime, select your Apple ID and tap Sign Out.
> - If the phone number that you want to remove belongs to an iPhone that you can't access, change your Apple ID password. This removes all phone numbers from your iPad, iPod touch, and Mac. Calls or messages for the removed numbers won't appear on those devices anymore.